# Powershell Get-Item cannot find path

Tags: windows, powershell, acl

I am working on a Powershell script to change the ACL of a folder (the $Recycle.Bin folder actually) but I am stuck at actually applying the permission on the folder because the Get-Item cmdlet does not find the path.

Here's (part of) the script:

```
$acl = Get-Acl "$env:USERPROFILE\`$Recycle.Bin"
$AccessRule = New-Object System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemAccessRule("BUILTIN\Users",'FullControl', 'ContainerInherit, ObjectInherit', 'None', 'Allow')
$acl.SetAccessRule($AccessRule)
(Get-Item "$env:USERPROFILE\`$Recycle.Bin").SetAccessControl($acl)
```

The error I am getting is that the path cannot be found:

```
Get-Item : Could not find item C:\Users\TestUser\$Recycle.Bin.
At line:1 char:2
+ (Get-Item "$env:USERPROFILE\`$Recycle.Bin").SetAccessControl($acl)
+  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (C:\Users\test\$Recycle.Bin:String) [Get-Item], IOException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ItemNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetItemCommand

You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.
At line:1 char:1
+ (Get-Item "$env:USERPROFILE\`$Recycle.Bin").SetAccessControl($acl)
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvokeMethodOnNull
```

The `Get-Item` cmdlet cannot find the path but I can succesfully navigate to it using the `CD` command:

```
PS C:\Users\TestUser> cd "$env:USERPROFILE\`$Recycle.Bin"
PS C:\Users\RestUser\$Recycle.Bin>
```

I suspect that it's because the $Recycle.Bin folder has a " $ " in the path but then again I believe it shouldn't be interpreted as a variable since I added the " ` " character to it.

I may be wrong about this though.

It may be good to point out that this path is actually a User Profile Disk (so a VHDX) that is mounted to the server.

How can I make it so that the `Get-Item` cmdlet can actually find the path?

Thank you!

Comment: have you confirmed that the `$env:` stuff is getting filled in at that point in your code? does `Get-Item "$env:USERPROFILE\`$Recycle.Bin"` work in the environment that your script is running in? it does NOT work in my setup. i'm trying to figure out why ...

Comment: That is because that is not an $env: property, nor is that where the Recycle.Bin is. 
It is here: To access the Recycle Bin folder, paste C:\$Recycle.Bin in Run.

Comment: @postanote - thanks - i found that out just after you posted the answer! [*grin*]

Comment: ;-}   Yeppers, I have this in my notes from a while back because of stuff I was asked to do .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your path is correct and not in the default location `C:\$Recycle.bin`, you just have to quote that path in single quotes to prevent PowerShell from trying to evaluate `$Recycle` which will most probably be a non-existent variable. You can get the ACL of the recycle bin like this:

```bsh
Get-Acl -Path (Join-Path -Path $env:USERPROFILE -ChildPath '$Recycle.bin')
```

If you want to get more info about it (like with `Get-Item`), you have to add the `-Force` parameter, as it is a hidden system folder:

```bsh
Get-Item -Path (Join-Path -Path $env:USERPROFILE -ChildPath '$Recycle.bin') -Force
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. The `- Force` option did the trick! Also, you are correct in saying that the Recycle Bin folder is located on the ` C:\ ` drive but since this is a Terminal Server and they are using User Profile Disks, there also is a '$Recycle.Bin' folder in each user profile.

Comment: @Noct03 Thx for your feedback. I updated my answer to reflect the fact that your path is correct.

Answer (score 0):

That is because that is not an $env: property, nor is that where the Recycle.Bin is.

It is here: To access the Recycle Bin folder, paste...

```
C:\$Recycle.Bin
```

...in Run.

One can also use this to access it:

[Get-RecycleBin](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/Get-RecycleBin-shows-the-085d12b0) - shows the contents of the Recycle Bin
This function is intended to compliment the Clear-RecycleBin cmdlet, which does not provide the functionality to view the files that are stored in the Recycle-Bin.

Download:  [Get-RecycleBin.ps1](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/Get-RecycleBin-shows-the-085d12b0/file/142875/1/Get-RecycleBin.ps1)